# Can't play live streaming after SHA256 using wowza Security token V2

Tags: live-streaming, playback, wowza

I am using Wowza Stream Engine and I Enabled Outgoing security with Wowza SecurityToken Version 2.5.9

I am trying to do a client server authentication. I followed following steps as described in

https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-protect-streaming-using-securetoken-in-wowza-streaming-engine

Following are the configuration I set in wowza playback security

[image]

And here is my incoming stream

[image]

The issue is when I run the resulted url after encoding with SHA256 and converting it to Base 64 as per instructed in the above documentation link. It gives me **403 Access Denied Error**. But when I **removed** my PlayBack security   in wowza engine. It streams perfect.

Has anyone experienced same issue using wowza Streaming Engine and GoCoder for source streaming.

Comment: have you fixed this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I'm appending token in the URL but still I'm not able to play video on test android app.